# Get first character of string and save in variable

Tags: swift, string

I'm trying to get the first letter of a string and store it in another variable which is a string.

So far I have

```
func getFirstChar(deckName : String) -> String {
    return String(deckName.first)
}
```

From what I understand from googling this should work, but it doesn't compile with the error

> No exact matches in call to initializer

Comment: `String(deckName.prefix(1))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Joan says, `String.first` returns an `Optional`. I'm always leery about using force-unwrapping since it crashes if the thing you are unwrapping is nil, so I would advise against the suggestion of using it to return a non optional string.

---

### Edit

Leo Dabus pointed out that you could write this function using `String.prefix(_:)`, which (apparently) doesn't return an Optional. That lets you avoid all that mucking about with optionals. That version of the function might look like this:

```
func getFirstChar(_ deckName : String) -> String {
    return String(deckName.prefix(1))
}
```

---

Below are other options of dealing with the optionals returned by `String.first`:

I'd suggest a variation on Joan's answer instead:

```
func getFirstChar(_ deckName : String) -> String {
    return String(deckName.first ?? Character(""))
}
```

Or

```
func getFirstChar(_ deckName : String) -> String {
    return deckName.first.map {String($0)} ?? ""
}
```

Either of those versions will return an empty string if `first` returns `nil` (a reasonable return value.)

A third choice is to return an Optional string:

```
func getFirstChar(_ deckName : String) -> String? {
    return deckName.first.map {String($0)}
}
```

Comment: How do you know `joan` is a she? It's a masculine name in the parts of Spain where it is used. I'd be more leery of pronoun assumptions if I were you; it is possible to rewrite without using any and I have done so. I'd advise being more careful in future; if the user doesn't provide explicit pronoun information, don't use them.

Comment: Much easier to use `String(deckName.prefix(1))` which doesn’t return an optional

Comment: @Matt, good point on pronouns. Fraught subject, and best not to make assumptions.

Comment: @LeoDabus That is a much better solution. Off to edit my answer...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `first` produces an optional. If you are sure that the deck name won't be nil then use this:

```
func getFirstChar(_ deckName : String) -> String {
        return String(deckName.first!)
    
}
```